# Add-in express. After installing few plugins outlook not close

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins

After installing a few plugins, Outlook does not close. Plugins used Add-In Express version 6.

I found a [blog post](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/10/09/problem-detected-addin-disabled-outlook2013/) that says to just change the DLLs to version 7. I changed `adxloader` and `adxregistrator` but unfortunately it did not help.

Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be one of the new add-ins that you installed that's not properly releasing internal objects.  Try disabling them one by one until you've isolated the problem add-in.